# NullReferenceException em C#

Tags: c#, exceção

Estou com um problema em C#, estou me deparando com uma exceção e não consigo reconhecer o porque da mesma

Detalhes da Exceção:

> System.NullReferenceException: "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Trecho de código que lança a exceção é:

```
public void AdicionarCliente(String nome, String sobrenome)
{
    Clientes.Add(new Cliente(nome, sobrenome));
}
```

Na classe:

```
public sealed class Banco
{
    private static readonly Banco instance = new Banco();
    public static Banco Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private List<Cliente> Clientes;

    private Banco()
    {
    }

    public void AdicionarCliente(String nome, String sobrenome)
    {
        Clientes.Add(new Cliente(nome, sobrenome));
    }

    public int GetNumeroDeClientes()
    {
        return Clientes.Count;
    }

    public Cliente GetCliente(int indice)
    {
        return Clientes[indice];
    }
}
```

Classe Cliente:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public String Nome
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public String Sobrenome
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    private List<Conta> Contas { set; get; }

    public Cliente(String nome, String sobrenome)
    {
        this.Nome = nome;
        this.Sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }

    public Conta GetConta(int indice)
    {
        return Contas[indice];
    }

    public int GetNumeroDeContas()
    {
        return Contas.Count;
    }

    public void AdicionarConta(Conta c)
    {
        Contas.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é porque a lista de clientes não foi instanciada.

Não tenho como saber qual é o momento certo de instanciá-la, mas se for logo na inicialização você pode fazer direto na declaração

```
private List<Cliente> Clientes = new List<Cliente();
```